# Google Translate override select change event

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-translate

I've got a wierd issue:

```
<div id="translate">
    <a href="#" id="google-translate" title="Google translate">Translate</a>
         <div id="google_translate_element" style="display:none">
         <script>
         function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: "sv" }, "google_translate_element");
         };
         </script>
     </div>
</div>
```

Which gives me the following:

```
<div class="skiptranslate goog-te-gadget" style="">
  <div id=":1.targetLanguage">
    <select class="goog-te-combo">
    </select>
  </div>
    Powered by
  <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
  </span>
</div>
```

I cannot however seem to hijack the change event being triggered when selecting a new language.

I've tried by doing the following:

```
var $textfield = find("#google-translate");
var $popup = find("#google_translate_element");
var $select = $popup.find("select");

$textfield.click(function () {
    $popup.fadeIn("fast");
    return false;
});

$select.bind("change", function () {
    $popup.fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Have anyone got a solution for this?

BR, Henric

Comment: Which event are you trying to _hijack_? Do you mean the `onchange` event on the `select` element?

Comment: I want to see when the user changes language. Since this selection box is usually hidden. I want to re-hide it upon select.
I've tried adding: 
var $gadget = find("#google_translate_element");
var $select = $gadget.find("select");

$select.bind("change", function () {
        $gadget.fadeOut("fast");
    });

BR, Henric

Comment: The code you've given appear incomplete and it makes it difficult to come up with ideas how to resolve your problem. Maybe you want to put a demo of what you're trying into a JSFiddle.net like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4c5f5/.

Comment: Sorry if I've missed something, but the solution has now been found. Thanks fo all your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this by using a reoccuring check on the language.
Not the prettiest solution, but it does the job. :)

```
var firstMenuValue = $("#main-menu li:first").text();

var checkIfTranslated = function () {
    var check = function () {

        if (firstMenuValue != $("#main-menu li:first").text()) {
            firstMenuValue = $("#main-menu li:first").text();
            $("#google_translate_element").fadeOut("fast");
        }

    };
    setInterval(check, 2000);
};

checkIfTranslated();
```

I hope this helps out somebody at least.

Answer (score 3):

The code below suggested by MjrKusanagi works wonderfully.

```js
$("body").on("change", "#google_translate_element select", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log($(this).find(":selected").text());
    console.log($(this).find(":selected").val());
});
```

To view all data inside the drop down

```js
$(".goog-te-combo").find("option").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).text() + ", " + $(this).val() + "\n");
});
```

Comment: Is there any chance to post full working code with HTML in JSFIDDLE or some thing similar ?

Comment: I had an issue when I had layout parameter set  , it wasn't select->option element. When I removed the layout it started to work. Can you post an example without Jquery. Because I use it on static single page without JS (Single HTML without any dependencies).

Comment: Yes, this works as long as the Google Translate element is a Select. I found that either having too many target languages or activating "source page contains multiple languages" turns the Google Translate element into a div, which seems impossible to latch on to.

Comment: it should not change by itself, I think you can set layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you would need to verify that the HTML from Google has been injected before running your JS code.

I can't seem to find a callback event on the TranslateElement just make a check for a HTML item you know is suppose to be there before running your code.
[Google Translate Widget - Translation complete callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894222/google-translate-widget-translation-complete-callback)

Comment: You don't need to know if the item is there or not. You can use the jQuery `.on()` method to bind the event handler to some parent of the target element. Example: `$('body').on('change','#google_translate_element select',function(ev){/*do fun stuff here*/});`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me flawlessly:

```
$("body").on("change", ".goog-te-combo", function (e) {
        if($(".goog-te-combo").val() == 'ar'){
            $("html").children().css("direction","rtl");
        }
        else{
            $("html").children().css("direction","ltr");
        }
    });
```

This is how I change the page direction from ltr (left-to-right) to rtl (right-to-left) when Arabic (ar) is selected as language, and vice-versa.